# do_docker.sh failing on console_bridge

Tags: ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the instructions for setting up ROS for Android found [here](http://wiki.ros.org/android_ndk/Tutorials/BuildingNativeROSPackages).  I'm installed this on Ubuntu 14.04.  I've got this issue on a system with Android NDK/SDK already setup as well as a clean install of Ubuntu.

After some time the failure is CMake looking for `console_bridge package` at `/usr/share/console_bridge` which does not exist. I've tried finding info regarding this failure and installing `console_bridge` but at the moment I'm stumped.

After some time `do_docker.sh` fails with the following output:

```
-- ==> add_subdirectory(class_loader)
-- Boost version: 1.53.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   system
CMake Error at /usr/share/console_bridge/cmake/console_bridge-config.cmake:12 (message):
  Library 'console_bridge' in package console_bridge is not installed
  properly
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  class_loader/CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/opt/roscpp_output/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed

Installing.

make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
build_cpp.sh /opt/roscpp_output died with error code 2
rob@rob-VirtualBox:~/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android$ sudo apt-get install console-bridge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package console-bridge
rob@rob-VirtualBox:~/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android$ sudo apt-get install console_bridge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package console_bridge
```

---

Edit: I dug further through the logs.  Looks like `console_bridge` is failing to compile:

```
/opt/roscpp_output/libs/console_bridge/src/console.cpp:60:5: error: 'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
/opt/roscpp_output/libs/console_bridge/src/console.cpp: In function 'void console_bridge::noOutputHandler()':
/opt/roscpp_output/libs/console_bridge/src/console.cpp:83:43: error: 'lock_guard' is not a member of 'std'
/opt/roscpp_output/libs/console_bridge/src/console.cpp:83:59: error: 'mutex' is not a member of 'std'
/opt/roscpp_output/libs/console_bridge/src/console.cpp:83:87: error: 'struct DefaultOutputHandler' has no member named
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226277/do_docker.sh-failing-on-console_bridge/) by [bd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25912/bd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-11**:
Please don't use answers to post updates (this is not a forum), edit your original question for that (use the *edit* link/button for that). I've already merged your answer into your question, but please keep it in mind next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for the delay, I've just seen this.

We've already fixed that issue ([here](https://github.com/ekumenlabs/roscpp_android/commit/1af05d649f0c313ae129fdb5c3fd2fffa01551d5)), it turns out, console_bridge move from using boost to using std C++11 mutex which is not currently available for the android_ndk.

If you update the repository, it should work.

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2016-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0